# How can I call a contract with a type parameter?

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I have the following contract:

```
parameter (pair :doc (string %name) (string %sig));
storage (list (pair :doc (string %name) (string %sig)));
code { DUP ;
       DIP { CDR @storage_slash_1 } ;
       CAR @parameter_slash_2 ;
       SWAP ;
       SWAP ;
       CONS ;
       NIL operation ;
       PAIR };
```

How can I call this contract with an `doc` type as parameter? All the example I find use a single string or int as parameter.

I have been trying:

`tezos-client transfer 0 from yolo to docs --arg '{ name = "test"; sig = "abcd" }'`

But I guess that is how liquidity expresses parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Michelson spec](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/michelson.html) you need to use the correct calling convention. You should use the following:

```
(Pair "this is a string" "a signature string")
```

One other obeservation - Why do you have SWAP repeated? This effectively returns the stack to how it was.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The Micelson code was transpiled from ReasonML -> Liquidity -> Michelson, perhaps not optimal. I need to dig into the Michelson spec, and I'll be sure to look into why the code is adding that repeated SWAP  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `next` branch of Liquidity, you can use :

- `liquidity CONTRACT.liq --call-arg main '{ name = "test"; sig = "abcd" }'` to print the argument to be used by `tezos-client` (where `main` is the entry point you want)
- `liquidity --re CONTRACT.liq` to directly compile a file in ReasonML syntax (add the `--re` argument in the previous command also)

(the double `SWAP` is under-optimized generated code, we will add a pass of optimization on the Michelson code in a later version)

Comment: Nice! Thanks for great feedback here  Will try the `next` branch 